# Nginx: javascript and css fail to load after changing url

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I wanted to add my blog, which is hosted in a different server, to my main website under subdirectory /blog.

The proxy through nginx went well

```
location /blog/ {
  proxy_pass http://107.170.8.156/;
}
```

I added also those lines to config.php

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', '/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', '/blog' );

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

It works fine, however it fails to load css and js files
[image: errors]

I searched everywhere on the Internet and I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: Are there any `location` directives on the main website which are intercepting all `.css` and `.js` URIs, perhaps to set the expiry?

Comment: yes, `location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
   expires 365d;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you have something like this in your config file:

```
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://107.170.8.156/;
}
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ { 
    expires 365d; 
}
```

The regex location will take precedence over the prefix location, and therefore, any URI ending with `.css` or `.js` will not be sent to the proxy.

You require any URI beginning with `/blog/` to be sent to the proxy, irrespective of file extension. Use the `^~` modifier to cause the prefix location to take precedence over any regex location. Try:

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://107.170.8.156/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Richard that came up with a new issue. I am not able to login to the admin area. All the open sessions are still opened, but when I try to log in from any other device or browser, it redirects to the same page without any error messages.